# Replacing android.jar provided with Terminal-IDE for newer SDK levels?

Tags: android, tablet, aapt

Background:  I have been using the Terminal-IDE program to learn about doing Android development (I like vim, for starters...).

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside

As shipped, it supports SDK level 9.  I want to support level 14 (Android 4.0+), so that I can use GridLayout instead of the more complex TableLayout.

I emailed the author, who responded in less than a day (kudos!), but, when I look for a replacement android.jar under /system on my tablet (Nexus 7 model 2), that particular jar does not exist, only many other jars with longer names that are just wrappers around dex files.

Anybody ran into this problem and solved it?

Comment: I'll admit this is a bit obscure, but I got down voted as a "bad question"???  Seems a bit harsh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further emails with the author of the environment, I found an easy solution:

- Go to the system/classes directory of the T-IDE install
- Rename the existing jar (e.g. - android.jar.t-ide)
- Copy the android.jar from the SDK (or sdk directory within Android Studio) with an alternate name (e.g. - android.jar.studio.sdk)
- Make a symbolic link from the updated SDK jar to android.jar

Now I can use GridLayout from Android 4.0 - compiles (*on the tablet*) and runs just fine.  I did not need to update any other environment variables or configurations, as I replaced the original android.jar with a sym-link to the updated jar (and an "ls -l" will show which one is being used as "android.jar").

Note:  if you get the updated android.jar from Android Studio, be sure to get the one in the sdk directory, *not* the one in the "plugins" directory, which won't work.

Comment: Will it also work if `new-android.jar` is in sdcard( no execute permission) ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't say.  My (android) tablet has since broken, and it was a Nexus with no card slot, anyway.